# PANDAS: How to leverage vector operations to find max value within groupby object

Tags: python, pandas

```
data = {"query":{"0":"playstation 4","1":"playstation 4","2":"playstation 4","3":"playstation 4","4":"playstation 4","5":"playstation 4","6":"playstation 4","7":"playstation 4","8":"playstation 4","9":"playstation 4","10":"playstation 4","11":"playstation 4","12":"playstation 4","13":"playstation 4","14":"playstation 4","15":"playstation 4","16":"playstation 4","17":"playstation 4","18":"playstation 4","19":"playstation 4","20":"playstation 4","21":"playstation 4","22":"playstation 4","23":"playstation 4","24":"playstation 4","25":"eye cream","26":"eye cream","27":"eye cream","28":"eye cream","29":"eye cream","30":"eye cream","31":"eye cream","32":"eye cream","33":"eye cream","34":"eye cream","35":"eye cream","36":"eye cream","37":"eye cream","38":"eye cream","39":"eye cream","40":"eye cream","41":"eye cream","42":"eye cream","43":"eye cream","44":"eye cream","45":"eye cream","46":"eye cream","47":"eye cream","48":"eye cream","49":"eye cream","50":"routers","51":"routers","52":"routers","53":"routers","54":"routers","55":"routers","56":"routers","57":"routers","58":"routers","59":"routers","60":"routers","61":"routers","62":"routers","63":"routers","64":"routers","65":"routers","66":"routers","67":"routers","68":"routers","69":"routers","70":"routers","71":"routers","72":"routers","73":"routers","74":"routers","75":"shaver panasonic","76":"shaver panasonic","77":"shaver panasonic","78":"shaver panasonic","79":"shaver panasonic","80":"shaver panasonic","81":"shaver panasonic","82":"shaver panasonic","83":"shaver panasonic","84":"shaver panasonic","85":"shaver panasonic","86":"shaver panasonic","87":"shaver panasonic","88":"shaver panasonic","89":"shaver panasonic","90":"shaver panasonic","91":"shaver panasonic","92":"shaver panasonic","93":"shaver panasonic","94":"shaver panasonic","95":"shaver panasonic","96":"shaver panasonic","97":"shaver panasonic","98":"shaver panasonic","99":"shaver panasonic"},"product_link":{"0":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/Sony-PlayStation-4-PS4-Latest-Model-500-GB-Jet-Black-Console-\\/321459436277?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item4ad879baf5","1":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/Sony-PlayStation-4-Latest-Model-500-GB-Jet-Black-Console-\\/131467224962?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item1e9c0ea782","2":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/Sony-PlayStation-4-PS4-500-GB-Jet-Black-Console-\\/171564913575?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item27f210d3a7","3":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/Sony-PlayStation-4-500GB-The-Last-of-Us-Remastered-Bundle-Black-\\/261867581805?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item3cf886316d","4":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/Sony-PlayStation-4-PS4-Latest-Model-500-GB-Jet-Black-Console-\\/121512215166?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item1c4ab1427e","5":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/Sony-PlayStation-4-PS4-Latest-Model-500-GB-Jet-Black-Console-\\/321739452651?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item4ae92a70eb","6":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/BRAND-NEW-Sony-PlayStation-4-BUNDLE-500gb-\\/281672602591?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item4194fed3df","7":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/Sony-PlayStation-4-500GB-Dualshock-Wireless-Control-HDMI-Gaming-Console-Refurb-\\/291398220855?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item43d8affc37","8":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/Sony-PlayStation-4-Latest-Model-500-GB-Jet-Black-Console-w-2-Controllers-\\/191563117865?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item2c9a0d3529","9":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/Sony-PlayStation-4-Latest-Model-500-GB-Jet-Black-Console-NEW-\\/191323651417?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item2c8bc73d59","10":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/Sony-PlayStation-4-Latest-Model-500-GB-Jet-Black-Console-wth-Mortal-Kombat-X-\\/261867577701?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item3cf8862165","11":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/Genuine-SONY-PS4-Playstation-4-500GB-Gaming-Console-Black-\\/281675418359?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item419529caf7","12":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/Sony-Playstation-4-PS4-Video-Game-Console-Black-Latest-Model-\\/221619727695?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item339990ad4f","13":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/Sony-PlayStation-4-Latest-Model-500-GB-Jet-Black-Console-\\/121492378177?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item1c49829241","14":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/Sony-PlayStation-4-500-GB-Jet-Black-Console-WITH-LAST-OF-US-REMASTERED-\\/181703768765?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_2&hash=item2a4e637abd","15":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/Sony-PlayStation-4-Latest-Model-500-GB-Jet-Black-Console-\\/321739448586?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item4ae92a610a","16":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/Sony-PlayStation-4-Latest-Model-500-GB-Jet-Black-Console-\\/281668431061?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item4194bf2cd5","17":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/Sony-PlayStation-4-500-GB-Jet-Black-Console-3-controllers-3-games-included-\\/141650033710?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item20fafffc2e","18":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/Sony-PlayStation-4-500GB-Console-with-2-Controllers-\\/181674777653?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item2a4ca91c35","19":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/Sony-PlayStation-4-500GB-The-Last-of-Us-Remastered-Bundle-Black-\\/271852505826?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item3f4bac0ae2","20":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/Sony-PlayStation-4-Latest-Model-500-GB-Jet-Black-Console-\\/191567367225?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item2c9a4e0c39","21":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/Sony-PlayStation-4-Latest-Model-500-GB-Jet-Black-Console-\\/261868106780?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item3cf88e341c","22":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/Sony-PlayStation-4-Latest-Model-500-GB-Jet-Black-Console-\\/131492408652?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item1e9d8eed4c","23":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/Sony-PlayStation-4-Latest-Model-500-GB-Jet-Black-Console-\\/251935643425?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item3aa888d721","24":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/Sony-Playstation-4-PS4-1105A-Video-Game-Console-500GB-White-Latest-Model-\\/331397300323?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item4d28d18063","25":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/NEW-Clinique-Repairwear-Laser-Focus-Wrinkle-Correcting-Eye-Cream-5ml-\\/141015736665?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item20d5316159","26":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/Obagi-Elastiderm-Eye-Treatment-Cream-0-5-oz-15g-Authentic-NiB-Sealed-5-\\/121451624128?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item1c4714b6c0","27":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/Lancome-Renergie-Eye-Anti-Wrinkle-Firming-Eye-Cream-0-5oz-New-\\/231520361001?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item35e7b05a29","28":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/OZ-Naturals-The-BEST-Eye-Gel-Eye-Cream-For-Dark-Circles-Puffiness-and-\\/251819088513?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item3aa1965a81","29":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/Elastiderm-Eye-Cream-0-5oz-15g-\\/271852609134?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item3f4bad9e6e","30":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/new-CLINIQUE-Repairwear-Laser-Focus-Wrinkle-Correcting-Eye-Cream-0-17-oz-5-ml-\\/151418586012?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item234140439c","31":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/NIB-Full-Size-Dermalogica-Multivitamin-Power-Firm-Eye-Cream-\\/331534991663?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item4d3106812f","32":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/24K-Gold-Collagen-Anti-Dark-Circles-Anti-Aging-Bio-Essence-Repairing-Eye-Cream-\\/171439126019?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item27ea917603","33":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/Clinique-Repairwear-Laser-Focus-Wrinkle-Correcting-Eye-Cream-Full-Size-5oz-15mL-\\/291408235326?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item43d948cb3e","34":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/NEW-Clinique-Repairwear-Laser-Focus-Wrinkle-Correcting-Eye-Cream-5ml-\\/141643099643?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item20fa962dfb","35":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/3-Clinique-Repairwear-Laser-Focus-Wrinkle-Correcting-Eye-Cream-17-oz-5-ml-Each-\\/271850259596?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item3f4b89c48c","36":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/Lancome-High-Resolution-Eye-Cream-95-Oz-Refill-3X-25-Oz-Plus-20-Oz-Lot-\\/161679604684?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item25a4dafbcc","37":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/NEW-Clinique-Repairwear-Laser-Focus-Wrinkle-Correcting-Eye-Cream-5ml-\\/251936161971?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item3aa890c0b3","38":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/Neutrogena-Rapid-Wrinkle-Repair-Eye-Cream-0-5-Oz-New-\\/221755779183?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item33a1aca86f","39":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/20g-Snail-Repair-Eye-Cream-Natural-Anti-Dark-Circles-Puffiness-Aging-Wrinkles-\\/400900136107?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item5d57829cab","40":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/Vichy-Neovadiol-GF-Eye-Lip-Contour-Cream-0-5-Fl-Oz-\\/141643942775?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item20faa30b77","41":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/Obagi-Elastiderm-Eye-Cream-0-5-oz-New-In-Box-100-Authentic-New-Packaging-\\/331533153857?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item4d30ea7641","42":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/NEW-Clinique-Repairwear-Laser-Focus-Wrinkle-Correcting-Eye-Cream-17oz-5ml-\\/231504943626?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item35e6c51a0a","43":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/Kiehls-CREAMY-EYE-TREATMENT-cream-with-AVOCADO-0-5-oz-FULL-SIZE-\\/291442921806?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item43db5a114e","44":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/Clinique-repairwear-laser-focus-wrinkle-correcting-eye-cream-5-oz-15ml-\\/171757581139?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item27fd8cb353","45":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/Caudalie-Premier-Cru-The-Eye-Cream-La-Creme-New-Anti-Aging-Eye-Treatment-\\/271844794220?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item3f4b365f6c","46":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/Jeunesse-Instantly-Ageless-New-Box-Of-50-Sachets-Eye-Face-Wrinkle-Cream-\\/191488765385?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item2c959eadc9","47":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/VELOUR-SKIN-EYE-CREAM-5-FL-OZ-15ML-NEW-NIP-ANTI-AGING-WRINKLE-CREAM-\\/171762640740?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item27fdd9e764","48":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/Shiseido-White-Lucent-Anti-Dark-Circles-Puffiness-Eye-Cream-15ml-53oz-Full-Size-\\/231416090984?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item35e1795168","49":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/Murad-Resurgence-Renewing-Eye-Cream-Anti-Aging-25-oz-NEW-Dark-Circles-Wrinkle-\\/141647993816?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item20fae0dbd8","50":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/D-Link-DIR-615-300Mbps-Wireless-N-Router-4-Port-w-Firewall-\\/221417068842?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item338d7c592a","51":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/Triton-MOF001-2-1-4hp-dual-mode-precision-Router-New-3-day-auction-\\/321735833636?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item4ae8f33824","52":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/Porter-Cable-3-1-4-HP-Five-Speed-Router-7518-Power-Tools-Routers-\\/181728302109?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item2a4fd9d41d","53":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/Linksys-EA6900-AC1900-Wi-Fi-Wireless-Router-Dual-Band-with-Gigabit-USB-3-0-Port-\\/301378755139?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item462b92da43","54":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/Linksys-EA6500-1300-Mbps-4-Port-Gigabit-Wireless-AC-Router-\\/261859894284?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item3cf810e40c","55":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/Makita-RT0700CX3-1-1-4-Horsepower-Compact-Router-Kit-Trimmer-NEW-\\/331535015609?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item4d3106deb9","56":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/NETGEAR-R6250-AC1600-Smart-WiFi-Dual-Band-Gigabit-Router-802-11ac-300-1300-Mbps-\\/331538466703?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item4d313b878f","57":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/NETGEAR-Nighthawk-AC1900-Dual-Band-Wi-Fi-Gigabit-Router-R7000-BRAND-NEW-SEALED-\\/131493764346?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item1e9da39cfa","58":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/Netgear-WNDR3400-N600-Wireless-Dual-Band-Router-WNDR3400-100-\\/171742747875?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item27fcaa5ce3","59":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/Netgear-N600-300-Mbps-4-Port-10-100-Wireless-N-Router-WNDR3400-\\/321732099037?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item4ae8ba3bdd","60":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/NETGEAR-N600-WNDR3400-Wireless-Dual-Band-Router-F-S-\\/371314644524?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item567413d62c","61":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/Netgear-NIGHTHAWK-AC1900-1300-Mbps-4-Port-Gigabit-Wireless-AC-Router-R7000-\\/111655240550?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item19ff2bc366","62":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/Netgear-N900-450-Mbps-4-Port-Gigabit-Wireless-N-Router-WNDR4500-\\/281668416613?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item4194bef465","63":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/Netgear-R6300V2-AC1750-1300-Mbps-4-Port-Gigabit-Wireless-AC-Router-\\/281672628800?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item4194ff3a40","64":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/Makita-RT0701C-1-1-4-HP-Compact-Router-With-FACTORY-WARRANTY-\\/181578856229?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item2a46f17725","65":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/CISCO-LINKSYS-EA4500-DUAL-BAND-N9000-WIRELESS-ROUTER-802-11N-UP-TO-450-MBPs-\\/301601427715?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item4638d89103","66":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/Netgear-N300-v-3-300-Mbps-5-Port-10-100-Wireless-N-Router-WNR2000-\\/261865282319?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item3cf8631b0f","67":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/Netgear-Nighthawk-R7000-2330-Mbps-4-Port-Gigabit-Wireless-N-Router-\\/261865168887?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item3cf8615ff7","68":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/Netgear-N900-450-Mbps-4-Port-Gigabit-Wireless-N-Router-R4500-FreE-ShiPPinG-\\/171763023276?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item27fddfbdac","69":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/D-Link-Wireless-Router-Model-DIR-625-\\/231542580777?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item35e9036629","70":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/D-Link-DIR-657-300-Mbps-4-Port-Gigabit-Wireless-N-Router-Hd-Media-Router-1000-\\/111656833712?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item19ff4412b0","71":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/D-Link-DIR-860L-AC1200-4-Port-Cloud-Router-Gigabit-Wireless-802-11-AC-\\/221756712042?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item33a1bae46a","72":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/D-Link-DIR-862L-Wireless-AC1600-Dual-Band-Gigabit-Router-\\/321732104185?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_2&hash=item4ae8ba4ff9","73":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/LINKSYS-AC1600-DUAL-BAND-SMART-WI-FI-ROUTER-EA6400-BRAND-NEW-\\/301604725310?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item46390ae23e","74":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/Netgear-AC1900-1300-Mbps-4-Port-Gigabit-Wireless-AC-Router-R7000-\\/281674411691?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item41951a6eab","75":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/Panasonic-ES-LA63-Cordless-Rechargeable-Mens-Electric-Shaver-\\/201337911294?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item2ee0acb7fe","76":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/Panasonic-ARC-5-Best-Mens-Shaver-\\/111651584739?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item19fef3fae3","77":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/Panasonic-Es8092-Wet-Dry-Electric-Razor-Shaver-Cordless-\\/111651556626?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item19fef38d12","78":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/Panasonic-ARC4-ES-RF31-s-Rechargeable-Electric-Shaver-Wet-dry-4-Nanotech-Blade-\\/321597257608?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item4ae0b0b788","79":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/Panasonic-ES3831K-Single-Blade-Travel-Shaver-Black-New-\\/351276044722?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item51c9af11b2","80":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/Panasonic-ES8103S-Arc3-Electric-Shaver-Wet-Dry-with-Nanotech-Blades-for-Men-\\/221755293448?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item33a1a53f08","81":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/Panasonic-ES8103S-Arc3-Electric-Shaver-Wet-Dry-with-Nanotech-Blades-\\/291427211284?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item43da6a5814","82":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/Panasonic-ES8243A-Arc4-Electric-Shaver-Wet-Dry-missing-cleaning-brush-\\/121545690510?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item1c4cb00d8e","83":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/Panasonic-Electric-Shaver-Rechargeable-Wet-Dry-Cordless-Foil-ES-RT51s-\\/251931974994?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item3aa850dd52","84":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/Panasonic-ES3831K-Single-Blade-Wet-Dry-Travel-Shaver-New-Sealed-\\/251856984391?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item3aa3d89947","85":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/Panasonic-ES8103S-Arc-3-E-W-O-POUCH-MANUAL-Mens-Wet-Dry-Rechargeable-Shaver-\\/181719323897?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item2a4f50d4f9","86":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/PANASONIC-ES3831K-Pro-Curve-Battery-Operated-Travel-Wet-Dry-Shaver-\\/201264418020?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item2edc4b4ce4","87":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/PANASONIC-ARC3-ES-LT33-S-WET-DRY-WASHABLE-RECHARGEABLE-MENS-ELECTRIC-SHAVER-NIB-\\/221751055080?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item33a16492e8","88":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/Panasonic-ES-LV81-k-Arc-5-Wet-Dry-Rechargeable-Mens-Foil-Shaver-New-\\/221751343180?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item33a168f84c","89":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/NEW-Panasonic-ES-RF31-S-4-Blade-Mens-Electric-Razor-Wet-Dry-Factory-Sealed-\\/291443144053?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item43db5d7575","90":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/Panasonic-ES8243A-E-Arc4-Mens-Electric-Shaver-Wet-Dry-\\/181670746515?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item2a4c6b9993","91":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/Panasonic-ES-3833-Wet-Dry-Men-Shaver-Razor-Battery-Operate-Compact-Travel-ES3833-\\/261300467953?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item3cd6b8b8f1","92":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/Panasonic-Pro-Curve-ES3831K-Shaver-Dry-Wet-Technology-Stainless-Steel-Foil-\\/400907349382?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item5d57f0ad86","93":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/Panasonic-Wet-and-Dry-Shaver-ES-RW30s-ES-RW30-S-\\/161543065028?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item259cb78dc4","94":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/Panasonic-ES-LF51-A-Arc4-Electric-Shaver-Wet-Dry-with-Flexible-Pivoting-Head-\\/201322707162?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item2edfc4b8da","95":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/Panasonic-ES8103S-Arc3-Mens-Electric-Shaver-Wet-Dry-with-Nanotech-Blades-\\/251927885898?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item3aa812784a","96":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/panasonic-ARC3-shaver-es8103s-\\/331535358676?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item4d310c1ad4","97":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/Panasonic-ES-534-Mens-Electric-Shaver-New-ES534-Battery-Operated-Compact-Travel-\\/261304623906?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item3cd6f82322","98":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/Panasonic-Portable-Shaving-Machine-Cclippers-Washable-Single-Blade-Shaver-Brush-\\/321716684950?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item4ae7cf0896","99":"http:\\/\\/www.ebay.com\\/itm\\/Panasonic-Arc3-ES-8103S-Wet-Dry-Rechargeable-Shaver-A491-\\/321712866709?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item4ae794c595"},"relevance":{"0":3.67,"1":4.0,"2":4.0,"3":3.67,"4":3.33,"5":3.2,"6":4.0,"7":4.0,"8":3.75,"9":2.33,"10":4.0,"11":4.0,"12":3.33,"13":3.0,"14":3.4,"15":4.0,"16":2.8,"17":4.0,"18":3.0,"19":2.33,"20":4.0,"21":4.0,"22":4.0,"23":4.0,"24":4.0,"25":4.0,"26":3.4,"27":4.0,"28":3.75,"29":4.0,"30":4.0,"31":4.0,"32":4.0,"33":3.67,"34":3.75,"35":4.0,"36":4.0,"37":4.0,"38":4.0,"39":3.4,"40":3.0,"41":4.0,"42":4.0,"43":4.0,"44":4.0,"45":4.0,"46":3.67,"47":3.67,"48":4.0,"49":4.0,"50":4.0,"51":3.0,"52":2.6,"53":4.0,"54":2.33,"55":1.33,"56":4.0,"57":4.0,"58":4.0,"59":3.67,"60":3.67,"61":4.0,"62":3.75,"63":4.0,"64":2.0,"65":4.0,"66":4.0,"67":4.0,"68":4.0,"69":4.0,"70":4.0,"71":4.0,"72":4.0,"73":3.67,"74":4.0,"75":3.33,"76":2.8,"77":2.0,"78":4.0,"79":3.2,"80":2.8,"81":4.0,"82":4.0,"83":4.0,"84":4.0,"85":3.67,"86":4.0,"87":4.0,"88":3.67,"89":3.33,"90":4.0,"91":4.0,"92":3.67,"93":4.0,"94":4.0,"95":3.0,"96":4.0,"97":4.0,"98":3.4,"99":2.33}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
```

I'm trying to wrap my mind around "vectorizing". It seems that with PANDAS you can apply operations across an entire dataset at once and that operation will be applied across rows with common indices.

For this problem, I'd like to be able to find the product links for each query that have the highest relevance score.

```
df.groupby(['query','product_link'])['relevance'].max().reset_index()
```

The above shows me the max for each query/ product_link pairing but does not filter out product links with a lower relevance score within each query.

```
df.groupby('query').apply(lambda x: x[x.relevance==x.relevance.max()])
```

This is significantly better, but I feel there's gotta be a way to do this using an index operation.

I'm thinking would it be possible to set the index to the result of:

```
df.groupby('query')['relevance'].max()
```

and then use MAP or something to essentially v-look-up for the product link associated with that index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**
With `transform`

```
df[df.groupby('query').relevance.transform('max') == df.relevance]
```

---

**Option 2**
With `map`

```
df[df['query'].map(df.groupby('query').relevance.max()) == df.relevance]
```

Comment: am I right in thinking that this should be faster than running a lambda function across each groupby object? I'm not sure how to write out the O(n) notation. If you could add any explanation around that, it'd be greatly appreciated:)

Comment: You are right... It should be.  But not because of improved time complexity.  You see 'Vectorized' doesn't mean `fast`.  It means to perform vector operations instead of loop operations.  Sometimes, those vectorized operations are performed using an optimized algorithm implemented in C that can reduce the time complexity.  But more often, you get an improvement simply because it's faster to do loops in C than in python.  Turns out using `transform('max')` is very fast.  Then we perform vector operations by comparing the results to another column.